# Selenium WebDriver : Login Script not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, login-script

I am trying to create a login script where i am trying to verify if the login is successfull or not.However, it throws NoSuchElementException.Any inputs to correct the script will be very helpful.

Below is the Page Class from where i am calling the Login method:

```
package abhi;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class PageClass 
{

    //Declare the WebDriver
    WebDriver driver;
    //Declare the Login Page Elements
    By Username = By.name("username");
    By Password = By.name("password");
    By LoginButton = By.className("ui-button-text");
    By OnlineCatalog = By.linkText("Online Catalog");
    By ErrorMessage = By.className("messageStackError");

    //Create the constructor with the same name as that of the Page Class
    public PageClass (WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    //Create Login Method

    public void Login (String Uname, String Pwd)           
    {
        driver.findElement(Username).sendKeys(Uname);
        driver.findElement(Password).sendKeys(Pwd);
        driver.findElement(LoginButton).click();            
    }
 }
```

And below is the Test script to verify the login where i am using below verification:

1)Print "Login Successfull" if Logoff link is available
2)Print "Login Failed" if error messsage is displayed
However, when i am entering invalid credentials, it does not read the error message by going into the "else if" and still keeps looking for the Logoff link and hence throws NoSuchElementException.Below is the test script:

```
package abhi;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

public class TestCaseClass 
{     
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException    
    {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
       "C:\\Users\\k746261\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
       PageClass object = new PageClass (driver);

       driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/login.php");
       object.Login("admin1", "admin@123");
       Thread.sleep(3000);

       if ((driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logoff")).isDisplayed()))
       {
          System.out.println("Login Successfull");
       }
       else  if (((driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logoff")).isDisplayed()==false)) 
        || ((driver.findElement(By.tagName("td")).isDisplayed())))
       {    
          System.out.println("Login Failed");
       }
       driver.close();
     }
 }
```

Comment: which element thorugh exception

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws **NoSuchElementException** as it cannot find the **Logoff** link on the page.You should wrap the code with a `try{} catch{}` block where you are checking if the element is displayed or not.Try modifying like this and see if it helps :

```
Boolean elementvisible ;
try
{
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logoff"));
    elementvisible = true;
}
catch (NoSuchElementException e) {

// TODO: handle exception
   System.out.println("Element not found : " + e);
   elementvisible = false;
}

if (elementvisible == true)
{
    System.out.println("Login Successfull");
}
else  if ((elementvisible == false) || (driver.findElement(By.tagName("td")).isDisplayed()))
{    
    System.out.println("Login Failed");
}
```

NB : In the case of positive test case(successful login), you can add a `WebDriverWait wait` to wait for the link to be visible.